# How can I prevent Duplicates from this SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, vb.net-2010

I have two tables 1. tdppackages and 2. tpdstop and I do a SQL SELECT INNER JOIN to create a TableAdapter with some info from both and I want to NOT add duplicate records. Here is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT     tdppackages.trackno, 
           tdppackages.shpmentno, 
           tpdstop.custname, 
           tpdstop.address, 
           tpdstop.city, 
           tdppackages.amtdue, 
           tpdstop.pkgs, 
           tpdstop.ndx
FROM       tpdstop 
INNER JOIN tdppackages ON tpdstop.ndx = tdppackages.stopkey
```

Comment: add the word `distinct` after the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 5):

Change SELECT to SELECT DISTINCT is the fastest way.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work with multiple tables and shipment field is not on both records.

Comment: @AlexMiami I don't understand your problem. A select distinct ensures that all rows in the result set are unique based on the contents of those columns. A row will not appear if every field returned matches an existing record in the data set. What do you consider to be a 'duplicate'

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be having composite key which you should include in `on` clause.
like

```
INNER JOIN tdppackages ON tpdstop.ndx = tdppackages.stopkey
And tpdstop.col2 = tdppachages.col2
```

Answer (score -1):

Do LEFT JOIN instead. Knowing the differences of [each join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) would be very helpful moving forward.